# how to get selected ranges type from datepicker antd

Tags: reactjs, frontend, antd, ant-design-pro

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nRuIG.png)

I have displayed all the fields for the ranges

```
onCalendarChange={onCalendarChange}
        onChange={onChangeDate}
        onOpenChange={handleOpenChange}
        open={forceOpen}
        placeholder={PLACEHOLDER}
        ranges={ranges}
        ref={pickerRef}
        separator="-"
        size="small"
        value={value}
```

**My Question is :
how to get the selected range from antd date picker.

I have tried onOK and onPanelChnages but I didn't find a way to get selected ranges typed as strings.

Comment: can you please provide more info like which package or library are you using, and other additional to understand the question

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/admiring-matan-oms63x?file=/src/App.js Hope this helps!

Comment: I'm using const DayJsDatePicker = generatePicker<Dayjs>(dayjsGenerateConfig);

const { RangePicker } = DayJsDatePicker;

Answer (score 0):

https://ant.design/components/date-picker#rangepicker

according to official docs, you can use `onChange`

```
onChange={(dates, dateString)=> console.log(dates, dateString)}
```

Comment: Thank You so much for your reply, but I want the selected range ie. Today, Month-to-date, this week and etc, I want this kind of value

Comment: I have already used this onchanges function as you saw in the above code

Answer (score 0):

Use this hope it will solve your issue

```
const onCalendarChange = (dates, dateStrings) => {
   console.log(dates);  // this will contain the selected range (start date 
   and end date)
   console.log(dateStrings);  // this will contain the selected range as 
   strings (e.g. "2022-12-20 - 2022-12-30")
};

<DatePicker
 onCalendarChange={onCalendarChange}
  ranges={ranges}
   ...
 />
```